# Не получается написать программу бинарного поиска элемента в двумерном массиве

Tags: java, массивы

Написал программу бинарного поиска в массиве, хотел сделать то же самое с двумерным массивом, но пока не доходит как, подскажите, пожалуйста

```
public class mass {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            Random rand = new Random();
            int arr[] = new int[20];
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {   //Заполнение массива
                arr[i] = rand.nextInt(50); // (Любое число от 0 до 1 умножается на 50)
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                System.out.print(arr[i] + " "); //(Вывод массива на экран)
            }
            System.out.println();
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
                for (int j = arr.length - 2; j >= i; j--) {     // Cортировка по убыванию
                    if (arr[j] < arr[j + 1]) {
                        int temp = arr[j];
                        arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                        arr[j + 1] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Введите число для поиска");
            int search = s.nextInt();
            int nX = -1;

            int L = 0;
            int R = arr.length - 1;
            while (L <= R) {
                int k = (L + R) / 2;
                System.out.println("k = "+k);
                if (arr[k] == search) {
                    nX = arr[k];
                    break;
                }
                else if (arr[k] < search) {
                    R = k - 1;
                }
                else if (arr[k] > search) {
                    L = k + 1;
                }
            }
            String s1= String.valueOf(nX);
            if (s1.equals("-1")) {
                System.out.println("Искомого числа нет в массиве");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Искомое число было найдено и равно " + nX);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: А как упорядочен двумерный массив?

Comment: MBo, двумерный массив также состоит из случайных чисел

Comment: Тогда от бинарного поиска никакого прока нет. Достаточно просто обойти весь массив, проверяя каждый элемент.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Принцип почти такой же, создаётся двумерный массив, затем ты переводишь его в одномерный и дальше по тексту...

Comment: понял, спасибо)